# Wrong date format on bean property

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces

I am trying to get date from p:calendar (2013-02-14) and pass it to the bean property. It's works but date format is not the same that I passed it.

Code:

```
<h:outputLabel value="Start date:"></h:outputLabel>
<p:calendar pattern="yyyy-MM-dd" showButtonPanel="true" navigator="true"  id="startDate" value="#{dodajanjeProjekta.start}" >
    <f:convertDateTime pattern="yyyy-MM-dd"/>
</p:calendar>
```

---

Value will must be 2013-02-14 but is Thu Feb 14 01:00:00 CET 2013

[image: On debugging]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A `Date` object stores a date as a `long` in milliseconds based around an epoch. That is the `fastTime` you can see.

When it displays as `2013-02-14` or `Thu Feb 14 01:00:00 CET 2013` both have the same value they are just formatted in different ways, you have to take timezone into account.

```
<f:convertDateTime pattern="yyyy-MM-dd"/>
```

is telling `jsf` to use a particular formatter when **displaying** the date it will still store it in the same way. The debugger on the other hand will just use the default formatting for the object when it displays it.

try using

```
new SimpleDateFormatter("yyyy-MM-dd").format(this.start)
```

in your expression window, you should see the date as you want to see it.